# Story where vampires are created by drop absorbed on neck?

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I have been trying to identify a book that I read maybe 25-30 years ago (1987-1992), in which there are vampire or vampire-like creatures, but instead of being created in the traditional way (e.g. bite on the neck), something drops a drop of a fluid on the back of their neck, which is then absorbed into the body and transforms them. I have a vague notion that some sort of tree is what creates these drops. The drops may have had a shiny metallic appearance.

I've tried to find this book before and always came up short. I'm starting to think the whole thing was a dream and I never read it at all. But I really feel like it was a book or at least a short story.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like [Brian Lumley's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Lumley) Necroscope series.  From book 1:

> But now the necromancer's scalp fairly tingled.  For suddenly he sensed a great strength in the vampire - and even greater cunning.  Quickly he stepped back - and in that same instant of time the pearly droplet overhead turned scarlet and fell!
>
> It landed on the back of Dragosani's neck just below the high collar line. He felt it.  It could have been a drop of moisture fallen from the tree, except it was totally dry here ... The vampire egg needed no ovipositor.  Like Quicksilver it had soaked straight through the skin.

Comment: That's it, thanks!